# Cisco Packet Tracer 8.0 won't start

Tags: applications

I have installed the application Cisco Packet Tracer 8.0.0 in my elementary OS but when I run it, it only shows the following: `Starting Packet Tracer 8.0.0`, and it won't start.

It's important to notice that I'm running the version 5.1.7 Hera of elementary OS and all the dependencies for Cisco Packet Tracer are installed.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem? Did you solve it? Thank you

Comment: Hello Carlos. Unfortunately, no I couldn't solve it. All I can say is that I switched to Pop_OS 20.04 LTS and works fine there.